# After Integrating Flyway with Jenkins, Not able to view DBMS_OUTPUT in console

Tags: jenkins, flyway

I'm using FLYWAY 5.1.4 Pro (Trial version)

```
 client : Command-line
 database :Oracle 12c
 operating system :Windows 8.x
```

I started by integrating Flyway with Jenkins ,then In `flyway.conf` file ,set `flyway.oracle.sqlplus=true`

After that I ran following Script-

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Script executed successfully');  
END;
/
```

In console, this message was depicted as
DB: ??? ,  instead of
DB: Script executed successfully

Any idea what will be the reason that the message is not rendered?